# evaluate a string like `sin(x)+3` with `x` given

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots, pgfmath

I defined a macro that gets as input a string like `sin(x)+3`, a starting `x` and an ending `x`, which is plotted using `\addplot` from PGFplots.

Now I want to evaluate this function for `x` equal to the ending `x` provided to the macro as an argument, to find out at what height the function ends.

The problem is: **how to evaluate a string like `sin(x)+3` with `x` given**?

I tried to use `pgfmathparse` but failed, and I know there are solutions with `\x` instead, but I want to use only the string `sin(x)+3`.

EDIT: Ok this is my code so far:

```
\renewcommand\line[2]{\addplot[domain=#1]{#2};}
\newcommand\dotted[2]{\addplot[dotted] plot[] coordinates{(#1)(#2)};\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(#1)};\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(#2)};}

\newcommand\pwpreviousset{0}
\newcommand\pwpreviousx{0}
\newcommand\pwpreviousy{0}
\newcommand\pwstart[1]{\renewcommand\pwpreviousset{0}\renewcommand{\pwpreviousx}{#1}}
\newcommand\pw[4]
{
\ifnum\pwpreviousset=1
    \dotted{{\pwpreviousx,\pwpreviousy}}{{\pwpreviousx,#1}}
\fi
\line{\pwpreviousx:#4}{#2}
\renewcommand{\pwpreviousx}{#4}
\renewcommand{\pwpreviousy}{#3}
\renewcommand\pwpreviousset{1}
}
```

The code above works perfectly, only i want arguments 1 and 3 of macro `pw` to be automaticly determined. These arguments represent the starting and ending y value of the function that is argument 2. I use them like this:

```
\pwstart{0}
\pw{1}{1+x}{4}{3}
\pw{-1}{2-x}{-2}{4}
```

But I want to determine the starting `y` and ending `y` programmaticly.

Comment: Please post your code, it is almost impossible to help without seeing what you have done until now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this, you need to define `x` to be a function, using

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={x=90;}}
```

Then you can use your expression in `\pgfmathparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={x=90;}}
\pgfmathparse{sin(x)+3}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to "undeclare" the function afterwards? Because I'm getting errors like "The function `x` already exists." if I try to use your solution for different `x`.

Comment: You can keep the definition of `x` local by enclosing the relevant part in `{...}`.